# Swing rendering of HTML table border

Tags: java, css, swing

From JavaDoc of `javax.swing.text.html.CSS`, it only provide limited support of CSS. Border is modeled but not rendered.

How to extend the class to provide the border rendering, where is the best start point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's CSS rendering certainly supports borders.  E.G.

[image: Swing controls with HTML border]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class SwingHTMLBorder {

    static String html = "<html>" +
        "<head>" +
        "<style type='text/css'>" +
        "p {" +
        "   border: solid 1px red;" +
        "}" +
        "</style>" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body>" +
        "<p>Do you see a border?</p>" +
        "<table border=1>" +
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>Cell 1</td>" +
        "<td>Cell 2</td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "</table>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(html));
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see the red border around the p tag on my XP system . I'm using JDK 1.6 u45 , is it the right JDK ?